# Removing index from pandas data frame on print

Tags: python, pandas

I'm really struggling to get this to print the way I want to. I've read through the documentation on removing index, but it seems like it still shows up. Here is my code:

```
quotes = pd.read_csv("quotes.txt",header = None, index_col = False)
quote_to_send = quotes.sample(ignore_index = True)
print(quote_to_send)
```

The text file isn't anything special, looks like this:

```
"When you arise in the morning think of what a privilege it is to be alive, to think, to enjoy, to love..."  - Marcus Aurelius

"Either you run the day or the day runs you." - Jim Rohn
....
```

The output of this looks like this:

```
                                               0
0  You may have to fight a battle more than once ...
```

How do I get rid of those random 0s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 0 on top is your column name, since you don't have one...

The 0 on the left is your index, something that absolutely every dataframe needs.

If you really want to see things without those essential pieces, you can use

`print(df.to_string(header=False, index=False))`

```
When you arise in the morning think of what a privilege it is to be alive, to think, to enjoy, to love...  - Marcus Aurelius
                                                                      Either you run the day or the day runs you. - Jim Rohn
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.to_string` with `index` and `header` as `False`:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({"0": ["some text"]})
print(tmp.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

Output:

```
some text
```